# errorHandle angular 7

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-errorhandler

How to manage error block in this situation - error managing in service and send to component

Here storing data in BehaviorSubject in the first load and subscribing data from where I need.

just initializing preload function from app.component  when the app runs - but I want to know here if its an error

```
//**app component**
//just initializing preload function() when the app runs - but I want to know here if its an error
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.preloadAllProjects();
}




// == services ==

//preload all projects
  preloadAllProjects(){
    this.http.get('/api/project/allprojects').pipe( map( response => response )).subscribe(result => {
      this.allProjectsBehavior.next(result);
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to follow the subject path:

```
//**app component**
//just initializing preload function() when the app runs - but I want to know here if its an error
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.preloadAllProjects();
    this.projectService.error$.subscribe(error => console.log(error));
}




// == services ==

//preload all projects
  error$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  preloadAllProjects(){
    this.http.get('/api/project/allprojects').pipe( map( response => response )).subscribe(result => {
      this.allProjectsBehavior.next(result);
    }, error => this.error$.next(error);
  };
```

or you can basically return an Observable from `preloadAllProjects`:

```
//**app component**
//just initializing preload function() when the app runs - but I want to know here if its an error
ngOnInit() {
    this.projectsService.preloadAllProjects().subscribe(success => {}, error => console.log(error))
}




// == services ==

//preload all projects
  error$: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  preloadAllProjects(){
    return new Observable(observer => {
    this.http.get('/api/project/allprojects').pipe( map( response => response )).subscribe(result => {
      this.allProjectsBehavior.next(result);
      observer.next(true);
      observer.complete();
    }, error => observer.error(error);
   });
  };
```

Comment: It's working if there an error  ,  but how to set time 'waiting for the error '  , I coudnt get error when I comment the line of code from server 
-------//return res.json({project: project, status:200});

Comment: Yes , Its taking too much time to get an error , is there an option to set time for waiting for http error

Comment: You can setTimeout in your subscribe method and unsubscribe after a certain amount of time. But that's a workaround. You will need to wait for the server error response.

Comment: Just to know, why we adding these two lines ?  observer.next(true);
      observer.complete()

Comment: To complete observable in case of success.

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the *catchError* operator, or pass a second function to your *subscribe* function.

Solution 1.:

```
preloadAllProjects(){
  this.http.get('/api/project/allprojects').pipe(
    catchError(err => console.error(err)), 
    map( response => response )).subscribe(result => {
      this.allProjectsBehavior.next(result);
  });
};
```

Solution 2.:

```
preloadAllProjects(){
  this.http.get('/api/project/allprojects').pipe(
    map( response => response )).subscribe(result => {
      this.allProjectsBehavior.next(result);
    },
    error => console.error(error)
    );
};
```